# SQL: insert records is not in order

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am having a problem while a record is inserted into a table. [image]

each parking_cost is inserted after its related record. It should be with its record. why is this happening?

Any ideas ?

Regards.

Comment: How are you inserting data into the table - can you post your SQL code?

Comment: @Sam: `INSERT INTO Customers(Parking_Cost) SELECT Parking_Cost FROM Parking WHERE Parking_ID = 1` I am taking the value of `Parking_Cost` from another table

Comment: Some very necessasry information is missing from your question. It looks as if you should be performing an update based on the results you are showing. Can you provide the schema for both the Customers and the Parking tables?

Comment: @Bill what I meant was why Parking_Cost = 5 is coming under Parking_ID = 9 , why not insereted in the same row of Parking_ID = 9 ???

Comment: @Human: Your questions seems so confusing, I would suggest you re-organize your questions first and try to understand what you are asking. Based on your previous questions, it seems like your questions does not justify on what you really wanted to happen.

Comment: In SQL databases (including SQL Server), there **is no implied** (or automatic) ordering - if you want order, you need to specify it by using `ORDER BY`. So in your case, you should probably define something like a `Sequence INT` column or something and then specify `ORDER BY Sequence` in your queries, to enforce that certain rows are displayed after one another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are doing two separate queries to populate the row in the table, the first query needs to be an INSERT, the second query needs to be an UPDATE, eg:

```
INSERT INTO Customers (Pre_Payed_Card, Parking_ID) VALUES ('1234', 1)
```

Then

```
UPDATE Customers SET Parking_Cost = <cost> WHERE Parking_ID = 1
```

An INSERT will always create a new row; two INSERT queries for the same logical entity will result in two separate rows like you have in the screenshot.

Update: re-reading that query, you're probably after something like

```
UPDATE Customers SET Parking_Cost = p.Parking_Cost
FROM Customers c INNER JOIN Parking p ON c.Parking_ID = p.Parking_ID 
WHERE c.Parking_ID = 1
```

Comment: thanks it worked but the problem now inputting it as an SQL statement in my web app, anyways Thanks alot !!